# How to print multiple lines with prefixes in loop without keeping to put each line repeatedly in python?

Tags: python, printing, prefix

I want to make this python code smaller because I can't load no more than a million lines in the code when I try to run it. This is an example of the code but I want to print prefixes 1-4 without putting them on a separate line each to save space.

```
import random                                                      
import string                                                      

while True: 

prefix1 = 'aaaaaaaa'  
prefix2 = 'bbbbbbbw' 
prefix3 = 'cccccccd'  
prefix4 = 'ttttttty'
print prefix1 + (x)[2:66].lower() 
print prefix2 + (x)[2:66].lower() 
print prefix3 + (x)[2:66].lower() 
print prefix4 + (x)[2:66].lower()
```

Could I code the bottom like this

```
print prefix1 - prefix4 + (x)[2:66].lower()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  your comment suggests that you haven't supplied all of your specifications.

Comment: "I have 1 million prefixes" is not a specification: "have" is unclear.  In what form do they exist?  So far, your only indication is that you happen to know the prefixes and can type them in, individually.

Comment: Its an unlimited loop

Answer (score 1):

Put your sequence of prefixes into a convenient sequence (a list, in this case), and iterate through that sequence:

```
prefix_list = ['aaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbw', 'cccccccd', 'ttttttty']
for prefix in prefix_list:
    print(prefix + (x)[2:66].lower())
```

Comment: What if I have 500,000 prefixes would I have to do that to all of them?

Comment: In some form, yes.  However, the way you would do that depends on the availability of the prefixes, how many times you need to iterate through the list, etc.

Comment: Its an unlimited loop

Comment: @DonVito Where do you have the 500000 prefixes?

Comment: @DonVito I am afraid I do not understand the other question.

Comment: @Goyo I want to print a python script down a list in a text file without printing a lot combinations, is that possible?

Comment: I d not understand that either. Maybe post a [mcve] with sample data, runnable code showing your attempt, actual output, expected output...

Comment: Please discuss question clarifications *under the question*, not as comments to an answer.